# Как сделать чтобы дочернии узлы корневых узлов формировались на основании разных таблиц?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Таблицы находятся во внешнем источнике (MySql, Acceess).
Синхронизация между "Treeview" и таблицами осуществляется через Dataset.
Т.е. должна выполняться синхронизация при следующих событиях: добавление узла, удаление узла, переименование узла, перемещение узла по дереву.

Как сделать чтобы дочернии узлы корневых узлов формировались на основании разных таблиц?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл с таблицами - [ссылка](http://transfiles.ru/yk4d7)

Comment: А в чем проблема? Используйте наследование

Comment: @Андрей NOP Вы бы не могли более подробно пояснить. Я только разбираюсь в программировании, не совсем понимаю

Comment: Ну вы вот задали вопрос, значит вы как-то пытались решить задачу и у вас не получилось? Опишите подробнее. У вас есть некая структура классов и вы пытаетесь отобразить ее в TreeView?

Comment: @АндрейNOP `Ну вы вот задали вопрос, значит вы как-то пытались решить задачу и у вас не получилось?` - не могу понять как подойти к этому вопросу. Как сделать дерево на основании таблицы это я понял, а вот чтобы для каждого корня отдельная таблица, разобраться не могу. Не могли бы вы подсказать по каким словам весит поиск?

Comment: Чтобы построить дерево вам нужен такой класс: `class Entry { public string Value { get; set; } public List<Entry> Children { get; set; } }`, вы можете из записей в таблицах сделать экземпляры такого класса?

Comment: @АндрейNOP `вы можете из записей в таблицах сделать экземпляры такого класса?` - буду разбираться. Дополнил вопрос. Цитирую: `Таблицы находятся во внешнем источнике (MySql, Acceess).
Синхронизация между "Treeview" и таблицами осуществляется через Dataset.
Т.е. должна выполняться синхронизация при следующих событиях: добавление узла, удаление узла, переименование узла, перемещение узла по дереву.`. Как в связи с обновлением вопроса измениться решение вопроса?

Comment: Никак, TreeView не умеет работать с DataSet, пишите нормальные классы